# Using character as argument to function

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to be able to only pass `q` as argument to a function, so that the user does not have to enter a string `"q"`.

I have a function defined in a module

```
Function doThis(val As Variant)

  MsgBox CStr(val)

  ' Here is a comparison of val with other strings and additional code

End
```

I call it from my worksheet:

```
=doThis(q)
```

And the messagebox returns

```
Error 2029
```

I have tried with String and Boolean as value type as well, but only variant fires the function.

Is it possible to receive a `q` as argument?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the question. Why would this not work `=doThis("q")`? Since you would be passing the letter q as an argument. Else it will try and evaluate q as an expression ( maybe not the right word )

Comment: If you're asking if you can pass a string parameter from a worksheet function without enclosing it in quotes, the answer is no.

Comment: The only way to do it would be to have a named range called q with its refers to set to `="q"`. Presumably, there would be other options besideds q, so you would also need named ranges for them.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this? I think we may have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: @Matt The reason is that i would like the user to be able to write e.g. e(x,y), where x,y is defined in the document as boolean values, instead of having to write e("x","y"). e(y,x) needs to be an option as well, so I can't just read and assign them from the cells where they are defined. Might be an XY problem as RubberDuck proposes.. I'l see if I can figure out the way Cool Blue proposes, or i'll try another approach

Comment: What do you mean "defined in the document"?  Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple.  First create a *Defined Name* for *q*

[image]

Secondly in a standard module:

```
Function doThis(val As Variant)
    MsgBox CStr(val)
    doThis = ""
End Function
```

Finally in the worksheet:

[image]

Comment: That simple. Thank you Gary